# How can I drill a grommet hole in my Ikea desktop?

Tags: drill, hole, desk

I have a computer setup that I would like to improve. My plan is to drill a hole through pretty much the MIDDLE of the desk in order to pass wires and make my overall setup look cleaner.

What I'd like to know is if I can drill a proper hole without damaging the desk when the table top is made of: particleboard, Ash veneer, Stain, Clear acrylic lacquer, Foil, Clear acrylic lacquer, and ABS plastic. To be specific, this is the [IKEA Bekant corner desk](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S69006392/).

Comment: If you have wires going through a hole in the middle of your desk, you may hook them with your feet if you stretch your legs. If you do this, attach some hooks on the underside to restrain wires.

Comment: Which is why usually you'd make the hole in the back third or so of the desk.  To keep the wires out of the way.

Comment: Buy or make a little channel to corral the wires behind the equipment and direct them over the back edge. Don't cut a hole in the **middle** of a desk. You or someone else may eventually want to use the entire surface and hole would ruin it. Ask yourself, "IKEA didn't put a hole there, should I?"

Comment: Also note that some IKEA furniture is only particle board arround the edges, the middle is corrugated cardboard.

Comment: Impressive, right now I have exactly the same problem with exactly the same table and "Hot Network Questions" was helpful ;)

Comment: For the benefit of future searchers - those plastic inserts are also known as "inkwells" due to a slight similarity with glass ink bottles sitting in a recess in the desk's surface.

Answer (score 20):

Of course you can, and it's very easy to do.

All you need is an appropriate hole saw.[image: hole saw]

Drill from the top down.  If you can, hold or clamp a piece of scrap wood under where you are cutting.  That will prevent the bottom from splintering.

Then to make it really look nice (and prevent any future splinters) you'll want a desk grommet that slips inside the hole.  Make sure you match the size of the hole and your grommet.

[image: grommet]

Comment: While the grommet should cover any minor splinters/chips I would recommend taping the whole area where the hole saw is hitting the veneer. Should mitigate any major splintering.

Comment: I suggest *starting* the hole from the top, then, when about 3/4 of the way through, finish from below. This will prevent tearout of the underside surface. Either that or finish with very light pressure and high cutting speed.

Comment: @isherwood agreed - you use the pilot drill hole as the marker and this lines up both cuts nicely.   Note the hole should be a firm fit, not a sloppy fit.  You can layer some masking tape around the fitting to take up some slack.

Comment: There should be 'grommets' available that are two sided to cope with the fact that many tables are hollow and you want the edge of the bottom hole to be connected to the top hole or you may be left with a vulnerable veneer edge underneath..